# phing + sftp to upload site as part of automated build

Tags: php, deployment, build-automation, sftp, phing

Does anybody know of an easy way to upload files to a remote server using SFTP from within a Phing build? I cant seem to find a custom or native Phing task to do this. The other problem is the interactivity of the SFTP unix command (requiring a password after reaching host, etc.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `SCP` (Secure Copy)?  It's directly supported by Phing (See the [scp Task documentation](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html#ScpTask) ).

For an overview of the differences, see [this website](http://geekswithblogs.net/bvamsi/archive/2006/03/23/73147.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use phing sftp task:
https://github.com/discont/phing-sftptask